# Tumblr. oauth_signature does not match expected value. 401

Tags: authentication, tumblr, sharekit

I'm using ShareKit for Tumblr.

May be someone had this error? I get this error if I try to login in Tumblr. Login was successful. After clicking on "Allow" button I got this error. Some months ago login was successful and I didn't have any errors. I'm sure that I haven't changed anything in my code.

Thanks, hope that anybody have already solved this problem yet.

Comment: I've the same problem, but it not because the URL is not in HTTPS :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was resolved. The problem was that the Tumblr updated the urls. Now they should be httpS:

```
self.requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token"];
self.authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize"];
self.accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token"];
```

Also don't forget to update ShareKit version to 3.0.2 and cocoapods to 0.35.0